# SQL Server query suggestion required

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem with returning certain records from a table - I am not sure if the result that I am expecting is possible using SQL. The following is my problem description.
The following table contains Order and child orders. The Child Order and Parent Order are linked by Parent Order and order type column.

My requirement is - if Parent Order and order type is specified all the records (parent and its child should be returned)
If one child is specified - then the specific child and the parent should be returned.

The table and the sample records are specified below - 
Please advise or suggestions.

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TEMP_ORDER]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMP_ORDER](
[OrderNo] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
[OrderType] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[ParentOrderNo] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
[ParentOrderType] [smallint] NULL
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEMP_ORDER] VALUES ('ORD0001',1,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEMP_ORDER] VALUES ('ORD0001@001',101,'ORD0001',1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEMP_ORDER] VALUES ('ORD0001@002',101,'ORD0001',1)


+-------------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|   OrderNo   | OrderType | ParentOrderNo | ParentOrderType |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| ORD0001     | 1         | NULL          | NULL            |
| ORD0001@001 | 101       | ORD0001       | 1               |
| ORD0001@002 | 101       | ORD0001       | 1               |
| NULL        | NULL      | NULL          | NULL            |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

The results will be like this - 
If OrderNo= ORD0001 and Order Type =1 is passed to the query - then all 3 rows will be returned.

If ORD0001@001 and 101 is passed to the query - then 
ORD0001@001 and ORD0001 would be returned.

Here is my Query

```
    select 
    TORD.OrderNo as WipOrderNo,
    TORD.OrderType as WipOrderType,
    TORD.ParentOrderNo as ParentWipOrderNo, 
    ChildORders.ParentOrderType as ParentWipOrderType
from 
    TEMP_ORDER TORD
    outer apply 
        (   select 
            ChildOrder.ParentOrderNo,
            ChildOrder.ParentOrderType
        from 
            TEMP_ORDER ChildOrder
        where 
            ChildOrder.OrderNo = @ORderNo and 
            ChildOrder.ORderType = @OrderType
            ) ChildORders

where ((
    (TORD.ParentOrderNo = @ORderNo and
    TORD.ParentOrderType = @WipORderType)
    or 
    (TORD.ParentOrderNo = ChildORders.ParentOrderNo and 
    TORD.ParentOrderType = ChildORders.ParentOrderType)
    )
    or (TORD.OrderNo = @ORderNo and TORD.OrderType = @OrderType))
```

Comment: Please include the expected outcome using the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an Order is necessarily a Parent or Child, no recursion is necessary, so simply query the table twice. First to get the specified orders, then to get the Parent/Child orders where applicable.

```
DECLARE @OrderNo [nvarchar](40) = 'ORD0001@001',
@OrderType [smallint] = 101

select 
    TORD.OrderNo as WipOrderNo,
    TORD.OrderType as WipOrderType,
    TORD.ParentOrderNo as ParentWipOrderNo, 
    TORD.ParentOrderType as ParentWipOrderType
into RESULT_ORDER
from 
    TEMP_ORDER TORD
where TORD.OrderNo = @ORderNo and TORD.OrderType = @OrderType;

insert RESULT_ORDER
select TORD.* 
from 
    TEMP_ORDER TORD
where exists(
    select *
    from RESULT_ORDER r
    where TORD.OrderNo = r.ParentWipOrderNo and TORD.OrderType = r.ParentWipOrderType
    )
or exists(
    select *
    from RESULT_ORDER r
    where TORD.ParentOrderNo = r.WipOrderNo and TORD.ParentOrderType = r.WipOrderType
    );

select * from RESULT_ORDER;
```